Next js (app router): I want to fetch data by hitting an api but i got error 405 (Method not allowed)
Here is my code
// client logic
React.useEffect(() => {
  const getComments = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/blog/comment/get-comments"
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      if (!response.data.success) {
        toast.error(response.data.message);
      }
      if (response.data.success) {
        const comments = response.data.comments;
        setBlogComments([...comments]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  getComments();
}, []);


// api
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import Comment from "@/models/CommentModel";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request) {
  dbConnect();
  try {
    const comments = await Comment.find({})
      .populate("author")
      .populate("blog")
      .exec();

    if (!comments) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: "unable to fetch comments",
      });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({
      success: true,
      comments: comments,
    });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      message: "Unable to get Comments",
    });
  }
}

The error I am getting:

GET http://localhost:3000/api/blog/comment/get-comments 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I want to fetch comments, thus using get I checked the syntax and url I am hitting everything but it still doesn't work!!

Is you API code in app/api/blog/comment/get-comments/route.ts?

yes just at last it is .js

Are you able to setup a test route and does it work? IE can you create a file in app/api/test/route.ts and just simply put in export async function GET(request) { return NextResponse.json({"status": "success"}) } does that also give you a 405 when you go to it?

i have an get route where i get the user data and does work
